# how to solve this differential equation when the function is an integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

By differentiating under the integral sign, I found that $\frac{dg}{d\omega}=-\omega g$ which is obviously a separable first order differential. I solved this, but I am trying to find the arbitrary constant. On the problem sheet, I am told that the standard integral, $\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\,dt=\sqrt{\pi/2}$, which I think should be used, but how?

[image]

Comment: Take the derivative wrt $w$ of the equation with the integral. Maybe it will give something. Or maybe there is a "special function" that is helpful. Also, try plugging it into wolfram alpha or symbolab online apps.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $g(\omega)=\int_0^\infty \cos(\omega t)e^{-t^2/2}\,dt$ and therefore

$$g(0)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\,dt$$

Can you find $A$ now?

Answer (score 2):

We have $Ae^{-w^2/2}=\int_0^{\infty}\cos(wt)e^{-t^2/2}$.

With $w=0$ we get: $A=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^2/2}$.

Clear ?